# android : how to change the style of edit text?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm trying to change the style of the EditText? Is it possible to achieve that? If so I'll appreciate being told about it, otherwise what alternative ways are available.

Comment: Style of edittext means? check here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Hope this will be helpful, http://www.androidworks.com/changing-the-android-edittext-ui-widget

Answer (score 29):

You can use the attribute `style="@style/your_style"` that is defined for any widget.

To define your style you have to create a file called `style.xml` in the values folder (i.e. `\res\values\styles.xml`) and use the following syntax:

```
<style name="You.EditText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

The attribute `parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText"` is important because it will ensure that the style being defined extends the basic Android `EditText` style, thus only properties different from the default style need to be defined.

Comment: Perfect! `parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText"` is what I was missing - without that, my EditTexts became read-only.

Answer (score 4):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/windowBackground</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    //apply Button style
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/editTextStyle</item>
</style>

//Button Style
<style name="editTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is definitely possible. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html (Raghu already postet that link) for more details.

You can also but a background in it, see this post: http://www.anddev.org/tutorial_buttons_with_niceley_stretched_background-t4369.html
It only covers buttons, but it is exactly the same for edittexts.