# How to change textsize in datepicker?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-datepicker

The default textsize in datepicker is too big for my app.  I've seen a way suggested to change it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837480/android-honeycomb-datepicker-text-color), but fishing around for the textviews nested inside the datepicker class seems clunky and error prone.

Is there a better/cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 10):

Setting a theme to `DatePicker` layout and adding `android:textSize` to it works for me.

In your layout's xml add a `DatePicker` applying a theme as shown below -

```
<DatePicker xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:theme="@style/NumberPickerStyle"
            android:datePickerMode="spinner"
            android:calendarViewShown="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
```

and then define the `NumberPickerStyle` in `styles.xml` specifying `android:textSize` like this -

```
<style name="NumberPickerStyle">
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/number_picker_text_size</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to change the font size of datepicker/timepicker/numberpicker is customizing the theme.

In styles file, set the default font size in the following way.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: works perfectly fine! Thanks for the quick solution.

Comment: but it makes all default fonts to 22sp in the project, I recommend this is not a good solution

Answer (score 3):

Sean's approach made some glitches in the UI of picker itself in case there're a number of pickers and I think it's not perfect to apply text size to all the components under the picker.
Below is what I've used and it works perfect without any UI glitches.

```
<style name="PickerTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/PickerEditText</item>
</style>

<style name="PickerEditText" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sean's code works. but it is changing font size for all the other components also(textViews, buttons, etc...) So Here is the solution.

Create different style for time picker and use it on time picker theme.

```
<style name="my_time_picker_style">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

and use it on your timepicker

```
android:theme="@style/my_time_picker_style"
```

Look at video, how I did https://youtu.be/JMJ2ujhk9c0

Answer (score 0):

use below code:

```
ViewGroup childpicker = (ViewGroup)datePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android"));

EditText mornthEt = (EditText)childpicker.getChildAt(1);// month widget

//change textsize and textcolor for mornthEt

mornthEt.setTextSize(30);

mornthEt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: for android 4.1+,1- "getChildAt(0)" worked for me not "getChildAt(1)" ,2- text size changes back when you spin up or down, this is not helpful at all

Comment: I would strongly suggest to not use this solution. the `getChildAt(1)` as it may brick when the order of the views changes inside the library. may work on a version and be broken with different implementations

Answer (score -2):

use below code

```
 DatePicker picker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dp_date);
    ViewGroup childpicker

     = (ViewGroup)
    findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month" /*rest is:
    day, year*/, "id", "android"));

    EditText textview = (EditText)
    picker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("timepicker_input",
    "id", "android"));
    textview.setTextSize(30);
    textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```