# android date picker increase font size

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I am using a date picker in my layout

```
  <DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/datepicker"
    android:layout_width="366dp"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:spinnersShown="false"
    android:layout_height="302dp"
    android:theme="@style/datepicker" />
```

I want to increase the font size of digits in the calendar body (1-31 digits)...checked for date picker properties..didn't find any...how I can achieve this?

[image]

Comment: try to use style for the date picker and increase the text size. Please let me know this works or not.Check this how to apply style http://www.materialdoc.com/date-picker/ and make the width and height as match-parent

Comment: You will need to write in java class instead to do it in xml

Comment: @KirtikumarA. any idea how to do it? I've already tried some...my layout contains a date picker, time picker and a button... all inside a  dialog popup

Comment: The design isn't very nice. It wont fit in small devices. Better use a separate time picker or use conventional date picker along with time picker instead of the current one which use a lot of area in screen.

Answer (score 0):

In above xml code dont try to add hardcoded layout_width and layout_height parameters instead of try to use match_parent or wrap content to set height and width to datepicker.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i don't have enough reputation for comment. I suggest you to take a look at this [How to change textsize in datepicker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727707/how-to-change-textsize-in-datepicker) before questioning please do the enough research.

Comment: are you using any third party datepicker