# Android WebView bigger DatePicker

Tags: android, html, webview, datepicker

I'm developing an Android Hybrid App for Tablets (Android WebView with local HTML5 Website). Inside my WebApp is a DatePicker

```
<input type="date">
```

Which looks like this:
[image]

It's very tiny on that big screen. So I was wondering if it's possible to increase the font size of that date picker or even to make it full screen.
Also is there a way to change the Theme of the DatePicker? I prefer a bright theme over that dark one.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> As i understood u want to increase size of font ... [visit this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727707/how-to-change-textsize-in-datepicker)

```
    <style name="datepickerstyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/editTextStyle</item>

    </style>
    <style name="editTextStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.EditText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_20</item>
    </style>


  <DatePicker
        android:theme="@style/datepickerstyle"
        android:id="@+id/timepicker" android:timePickerMode="spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
```

**update try below code to resize font**

```
DatePicker picker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dp_date);
ViewGroup childpicker

 = (ViewGroup)
findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month" /*rest is:
day, year*/, "id", "android"));

EditText textview = (EditText)
picker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("timepicker_input",
"id", "android"));
textview.setTextSize(30);
textview.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

///or u can below also

```
 ViewGroup childpicker = (ViewGroup)datePicker.findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month", "id", "android"));

EditText mornthEt = (EditText)childpicker.getChildAt(1);// month widget

//change textsize and textcolor for mornthEt

mornthEt.setTextSize(30);

mornthEt.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed my theme like this:
`<item name="android:datePickerStyle">@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker</item>
<item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>`
The theme of the date picker successfully changed to a brighter one, but the font size is still way to small.

Comment: did u check the link?

Comment: yes I checked out the link. But since I'm using an HTML5 WebApp inside a WebView I do not create the DatePicker myself.

Comment: i don't know this will help u or not but i want u to give it a try 
**WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
either setTextSize or

webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.SMALLEST);**

**i know this will increase size of webview font though try it**