# DatePickerDialog: how increase text size of year/month selector?

Tags: android, text, datepicker, themes, size

I know this is a subview and that's managed by internal view pager.
So how can I set custom text size?
This is my custom theme
[sample result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqE7O.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Check this link if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11727707/how-to-change-textsize-in-datepicker#:~:text=The%20easiest%20way%20to%20change,size%20in%20the%20following%20way.&text=works%20perfectly%20fine!

Answer (score 0):

Since `DatePickerDialog` is an external library, if it doesn't let you change it by passing some arguments, then one of the ways is to download the library locally so you can modify it to your needs.