# AppCompat DatePicker and TimePicker style

Tags: java, android, android-support-library, android-datepicker

I'm using a Theme.AppCompat theme in my application. Now I need to set the textColor of a datepicker and a timepicker to something like black, so I want to use the Theme.Appcompat.Light style for datepickers and timepickers, but I can't find a way to do this. Which parent should I use? Which property? TextColor is not working for me..

Comment: See this . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837480/android-honeycomb-datepicker-text-color

Comment: But I don't want to change the theme of the all activity..

Comment: only overwritte the changes that you define in the new theme.

Answer (score 1):

Create a theme and apply it only to your date picker.

using

```
android:theme="@style/yourTheme"
```