# What is the best way to change the text colour used in an android date picker view

Tags: android

I have my background colour for views in all activities set to black.
I try to use the standard date picker view. Unfortuneatley text seems to be black.
This makes it invisible. Up to now I have been using code to change some text.
I tried to do

```
    childpicker1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("month" 
    /*rest is: day, year*/,    "id", "android"));

    EditText textview1 = (EditText) childpicker1.getChildAt(0);


    textview1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

And this seems to initially work but when I try to scroll or select another value the text goes back to black so thats not good. Does anyone now what is the best way to change the text colour of the date picker in android ?

Comment: If you are loading this DatePicker from a layout, why can't you use android:calendarTextColor?

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for this from what I know that attribute only works in api 21 so only for the latest android. I am trying to support api 10-21 so my app gets wide reach. But thanks for the comment.

Comment: I seemed to be able to change color using the answers for this question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837480/android-honeycomb-datepicker-text-color                                    So I used a theme which seemed to do the trick. I just had to change the color to white and this updated the date picker controls.