# How to change Number Picker center text color in Android

Tags: android, android-datepicker, numberpicker

I have implemented a custom Date Picker wherein I need to have custom colors for the number picker (Date picker uses Number picker inside) inside it as follows:
[image: Expected]

With the help of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11595713/840669) I could make it look like this:
[image: Actual Result]

But as you see the actual date is getting shown in the yellow color instead of white.
Moreover, I tried doing it at run time like this:

```
npMonth.setOnValueChangedListener(new OnValueChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, int oldVal, int newVal) {
                EditText et = ((EditText) npMonth.getChildAt(0));
                et.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gold));
            }
        });
```

But still no luck.

How to change just the center text color to white and keep the top and bottom text yellow?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032921/544198

Comment: Well that's rather discouraging @PearsonArtPhoto. All is done except fzr the central text color and I'll have to switch to some third party libs. I think I should spend some more time fiddling with it.

Comment: @Rajkiran:I am also having the same issue. Can you please update the answer if you get the solution for above

Comment: @Rajkiran : Did you find the solution for your question ??

Comment: @codeRider and Krishna no luck folks.. unfortunately I haven't find any solution.

Comment: Did not try much after reading this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15032921/840669

Comment: @Rajkiran I'm interested too for a solution. I just finished wrapping up a custom number picker library (https://github.com/KasualBusiness/MaterialNumberPicker) that let you customize some of the most wanted private attributes, such as text color, but I can't color the center text only... Would be nice to come up with a solution :)

Comment: I also want the solution please help. In custom library no option for keyboard

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this

```
setNumberPickerTextColor(mNumberPicker);

public void setNumberPickerTextColor(NumberPicker numberPicker){
    int color=Color.parseColor("#333333");

    final int count = numberPicker.getChildCount();
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        View child = numberPicker.getChildAt(i);
        if(child instanceof EditText){
            try{
                Field selectorWheelPaintField = numberPicker.getClass().getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
                selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
                ((Paint)selectorWheelPaintField.get(numberPicker)).setColor(color);
                ((EditText)child).setTextColor(color);
                numberPicker.invalidate();
            }
            catch(NoSuchFieldException e){
                Log.e("setNumberPickerColor1", ""+e);
            }
            catch(IllegalAccessException e){
                Log.e("setNumberPickerColor2", ""+e);
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                Log.e("setNumberPickerColor3", ""+e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks