# Showing password in EditText like Linkedin "Style"

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-checkbox

I'm developing a APP for Android for educational purposes, and I see this in Linkedin APP. I like it!

Is a eye, and function is similar to CheckBox.

How I can do this?

Is a customized EditText?
Is a customized CheckBox inside EditText?

[image: **SHOWING PASSWORD**]
[image: **UNSHOWING PASSWORD**]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password box is probably a Horizontal Linear Layout with a background border surrounding it. For the edittext, it seems like a custom styled one, you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7188339/2426561) to figure out how to implement one.

Edit:
As for the checkbox, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3965484/2426561)

Answer (score 1):

just pass `null` to `setTransformationMethod` to show the password like --->

`yourEditText.setTransformationMethod(null);`

Comment: I know how to transform a password in plain text (anyway, thanks!). I'm speaking about the eye in right area in the EditText!