# Android Theming Preference Dialog

Tags: android, themes

I have an application that uses a preference activity to set some user settings. I been trying to figure this out all day. I am trying to theme the alert dialog when an user presses an Edit Text Preference object. A dialog opens up and the user can set the shared preference. The dialog pops up:

[image]

I want the text green. I want the divider green. The line and cursor green.

This is what I have so far.

```
<style name="CustomDialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:background">@color/text_green</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/text_green</item>
</style>
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or maybe share some code. I am at lost. I've been surfing the net to find something most of the day. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help lead to your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7188339/android-how-to-change-the-style-of-edit-text

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom layout or use a third party library, you can subclass `EditTextPreference`, then access each `View` you want to edit by using `Resources.getIdentifier` then using `Window.findViewById`. Here's a quick example.

```
public class CustomDialogPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomDialogPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    protected void showDialog(Bundle state) {
        super.showDialog(state);
        final Resources res = getContext().getResources();
        final Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        final int green = res.getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_dark);

        // Title
        final int titleId = res.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
        final View title = window.findViewById(titleId);
        if (title != null) {
            ((TextView) title).setTextColor(green);
        }

        // Title divider
        final int titleDividerId = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
        final View titleDivider = window.findViewById(titleDividerId);
        if (titleDivider != null) {
            titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(green);
        }

        // EditText
        final View editText = window.findViewById(android.R.id.edit);
        if (editText != null) {
            editText.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.apptheme_edit_text_holo_light));
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementation**

Replace `<EditTextPreference.../>` with `<path_to_CustomDialogPreference.../>` in your xml.

**Note**

I used [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to create the background for the `EditText`.

[image: Example]

Comment: Cool..  I'll give that a try... Can you basically use it for all preference dog types?

Comment: If you want to replace any `DialogPreference` with it then you'll need to subclass `DialogPreference` instead of `EditTextPreference`.

Comment: i assume you basically call the class like.. `<CustomDialogPreference ..../>` in your preference layout?

Comment: @user2252502 Yeah, I made an edit to my post about that.

Comment: so far so good... questions.. where did you learn this stuff. one thing I am struggling with android is a good reference

Comment: @user2252502 Practice. Some good references to start with are [Android Developers website](http://developer.android.com/index.html) or the [Android Developers Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers).

Comment: so i am trying to user the Android Developers Website to figure out how to change the ListPreference RadioButton color. I have the drawables I got from Android Holo Colors. I just not sure what to set. so far I have `final View radiobt = window.findViewById(?)`. I can't find anything that matches a radiobutton or radiobutton group. thanks for your help so far.. i trying to understand android a little better

Comment: You'll want to use the same structure as changing the title text color. But instead of casting `TextView`, cast `CheckedTextView` and instead of `TextView.setTextColor` use `CheckedTextView.setCheckedDrawable`. It should work if you're using the id `android.R.id.text1`.

Comment: So far this is what I got `final int checkId = res.getIdentifier("android.R.id.text1", "id", "android");
        final View check = window.findViewById(checkId);
        if (check != null) {
           //No method setCheckedDrawable
        }` Where did you get the info about what id is to what?

Comment: Browsing the [AlertController](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/app/AlertController.java#L200) source.

Comment: thank for the help.. the list preference didn't work..i ended up creating a custom list preference...

Comment: How would you do this using styles and themes in xml?

Comment: I got this error when creating this class.  There is no default constructor available in 'android.preference.EditTextPreference'

Answer (score -1):

You can build your custom layout for your own dialog theme using your own customized components or you can use external libs, for example [android-styled-dialogs](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs)

So in this case use can customize dialogs as you want:

```
<style name="DialogStyleLight.Custom">
    <!-- anything can be left out: -->
    <item name="titleTextColor">@color/dialog_title_text</item>
    <item name="titleSeparatorColor">@color/dialog_title_separator</item>
    <item name="messageTextColor">@color/dialog_message_text</item>
    <item name="buttonTextColor">@color/dialog_button_text</item>
    <item name="buttonSeparatorColor">@color/dialog_button_separator</item>
    <item name="buttonBackgroundColorNormal">@color/dialog_button_normal</item>
    <item name="buttonBackgroundColorPressed">@color/dialog_button_pressed</item>
    <item name="buttonBackgroundColorFocused">@color/dialog_button_focused</item>
    <item name="dialogBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
</style>
```