# Android - Style the input text color of sub-dialog of EditTextPreference in XML

Tags: android, colors, preferenceactivity, edittextpreference

Basically what this question is asking, **but in XML**:
[Change EditTextPreference dialog input text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51779376/change-edittextpreference-dialog-input-text-color)

[image]

The accepted answer is to write a whole class and edit each single element manually. This can't be the only solution. There must be some way to set it in XML styles.

I've tried this:

```
<!--  Preferences style  -->
    <style name="CustomPreferenceScreen" parent="DarkGalaxy">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightGray</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/hintText</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@color/hintTextDarker</item>
        <item name="trackTint">@color/prefs_switch_color</item>
        <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/PreferenceSubDialogTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PreferenceSubDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:background">@color/brighterGalaxy</item>
        <item name="android:textColorAlertDialogListItem">@color/lightGray</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightGray</item>
        <item name="editTextPreferenceStyle">@style/CustomEditTextPreferenceStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomEditTextPreferenceStyle" parent="Preference.DialogPreference.EditTextPreference">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/lightGray</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/lightGray</item>
    </style>
```

I think I'm just not hitting the right attribute, as it is buried in `PreferenceActivity > EdittextPreference > Dialog > EdiText inside the dialog`