# How to convert editText view in whole app from single place in android

Tags: android, ios

I want to convert `editText` view in whole app, from a single place, so that when we will have to change, we change it only one place.

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is called style or subclassing:

**Style**:

You define some attributes in your style (width, height, for instance) and you apply this style to all your `EditText`. Applying a theme gives the more or less the same result except that a theme is set for a whole `Activity` and not for UI Element. [More infos](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

**Subclassing**:

If you want to do something more complicated, you can subclass the `EditText` class and modify its attributes or method (you make a kind of ['custom' view](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) then).

Comment: Actually we have a app which is on play store , we have to do service of that app, now the requirement is  only change the  font size ,text color and layout.

Comment: Then I would create a style in the `styles.xml` and apply this style to all `EditText`, compile and do an update...

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to change the **behavior** of the `EditText` considerably, you should create a custom `View` class overriding (extending from) EditText.

If you are looking to change how it **looks** in the whole application, you should change it in your theme (`styles.xml`). Refer to this well-written answer to change the style of an `EditText` application-wide - https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188452/1086930

Comment: You can change the look in the subclass as well, subclassing is just more powerful...